# Categorize select with multiple DATE BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, sql

My question in title, so
If i had:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date BETWEEN "date[0][start]"
AND "date[0][end]" OR date BETWEEN "date[1][start]" AND "date[1][end]"
```

Can i somehow separate results in appliance with where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each condition evaluates to either FALSE (0) or TRUE (1). It is possible to select the results of the expressions as values and even sort the result by these values:

```
SELECT
    col1, col2, ..., coln,
    date BETWEEN "date[0][start]" AND "date[0][end]" AS first,
    date BETWEEN "date[1][start]" AND "date[1][end]" AS second
FROM tbl
WHERE date BETWEEN "date[0][start]" AND "date[0][end]"
OR date BETWEEN "date[1][start]" AND "date[1][end]"
ORDER BY first
```

Comment: To big, but it is solution.